# stringify() unexpectedly returns undefined when passing a field of AJAX response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a call to a web service and use `JSON.stringify` to get the different rows of the query but when I try to put it in a checkbox it says `Nombre Jugador: undefined` and `Correo[object HTMLInputElement]`

My code:

```
function cargarJugadores2(){
    var req = $.ajax({
        url:'http://zz27.infoucrso.com/WSS/WSJugador.svc/cargarJugadores',
        timeout : 10000,
        dataType : "jsonp"
    });

    req.success(function(datos) {
        var nombre = JSON.stringify(datos.nombre);
        alert(nombre);
        ProcesarJugadores2(datos);
    });

    req.error(function(){
        alert("No fue posible establecer conexión con el Web Service");
    });
}
```

And the second method:

```
function ProcesarJugadores2(datos) {
    var radiobutton = '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio" onclick="escribir()"><label for="radio" id="label">' + 
        "</br>Nombre Jugador: " + this.nombre + " </br> Correo: "  + this.correo + '</label>'

    localStorage["correoSeleccionadoAmigo"] = this.correo;

    $('#listaJugadores').append(radiobutton);
    $('[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
    $('#listaJugadores').controlgroup().trigger('create');
}
```

This is what the returned JSON looks like:

```
[{
    "Activo": true,
    "contrasenna": "1",
    "correo": "alex@gmail.com",
    "nombre": "Alex"
}, {
    "A‌​ctivo": true,
    "contrasenna": "1",
    "correo": "maria@gmail.com",
    "nombre": "Maria"
}, {
    "Acti‌​vo": true,
    "contrasenna": "1",
    "correo": "pedro@gmail.com",
    "nombre": "Pedro"
}]
```

Comment: what is the full printout of  `datos` in that success callback?

Comment: [{"Activo":true,"contrasenna":"1","correo":"alex@gmail.com","nombre":"Alex"},{"Activo":true,"contrasenna":"1","correo":"maria@gmail.com","nombre":"Maria"},{"Activo":true,"contrasenna":"1","correo":"pedro@gmail.com","nombre":"Pedro"}]

Comment: You're going to need to pass an index before you can access `nombre`. ie, `datos[0].nombre //"Alex"`

Comment: `datos` is a list, not a map object.

Comment: Loop over the contacts list before you access which person you want to grab the number from.

Comment: thanks to all it work how do I check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datos` you get is an array of objects. `nombre` is property of object inside the array.
In order to get one particular value,, first take array value and then look into object. So you code should be

```
var nombre = datos[index].nombre; //index will be array index.
alert(nombre); //no need to stringify nombre as you're doing array lookup.
```

Alternatively, if you're storing the JSON value directly, then stringify whole `datos`.

Answer (score 1):

This should get the correct outputs to the ProcesarJugadores2 function:

```
function ProcesarJugadores2(datos) {
    var radiobutton = '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio" onclick="escribir()"><label for="radio" id="label">' + 
        "</br>Nombre Jugador: " + datos.nombre + " </br> Correo: "  + datos.correo + '</label>'

    localStorage["correoSeleccionadoAmigo"] = datos.correo;

    $('#listaJugadores').append(radiobutton);
    $('[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
    $('#listaJugadores').controlgroup().trigger('create');
}

function cargarJugadores2(){
    var req = $.ajax({
        url:'http://zz27.infoucrso.com/WSS/WSJugador.svc/cargarJugadores',
        timeout : 10000,
        dataType : "jsonp"
    });

    req.success(function(datos) {
        datos.map(ProcesarJugadores2);
    });

    req.error(function(){
        alert("No fue posible establecer conexión con el Web Service");
    });
}
```

Using `datos.map()` you can execute a function on all the items in the "datos" array